# Blazor WebAssembly .Net Core Hosted - Delete temp file after its downloaded to the browser

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I wrote a report generator the other day which generates an XML file on the .NET Core server, as part of the generation it creates temporary files that need removing once the file has been downloaded into the browser.

I have this javascript function in the `index.html` which does the download into the browser:

```js
var downloadFromUrl = function(url) {
    var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = url;
    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();
}
```

Once the final report has been generated on the server I call the following to download the file and once complete delete the temporary files from the server:

```cs
try
{
    await JsRunTime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFromUrl", $"api/Export/GetExportFile?exportId={exportRunner.ExportId}&fileDownloadName={exportRunner.FinalExportFileName}&outputFormatType={exportRunner.OutputFormatType}");
}
finally
{
    await exportRunner.DeleteTempFilesOnServer();
}
```

This was working fine on a 100MB+ file.

I have today used the same approach to generate smaller files and am now hitting an issue.  It runs the `await exportRunner.DeleteTempFilesOnServer()` before

```
await JsRunTime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFromUrl", 
$"api/Export/GetExportFile?exportId={exportRunner.ExportId}&fileDownloadName={exportRunner.FinalExportFileName}&outputFormatType={exportRunner.OutputFormatType}"
);
```

so the download into the browser fails as the files have been deleted.

It feels like `JsRunTime.InvokeVoidAsync` is not being awaited.

Is there a way I can make sure the file has finished downloading into the browser before the delete kicks in?

Comment: It's far more likely that `downloadFromUrl` throws and execution jumps to `finally`. There's no need to use such a trick to download files though. You could create a proper `<a>` tag with the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute to make the server download the file. You can use Blazor to bind the `href` argument to a field or property holding the URL

Comment: By programmatically calling `downloadFromUrl` with the generated URL it automatically downloads the file into the browser. Your suggestion would mean the user would have to manually click an `<a>` tag as an extra step.  Then I would still need to delete the temporary files.

Comment: How did this work in the first place? The download is handled by the browser so `downloadFromUrl` should always return immediately. `a.click()` doesn't block the browser

Comment: That it worked for large files baffles me too. I would check that again carefully.

Comment: I'll have to double check the large files are consistently downloading.  I guess once the `a.click()` is invoked whether that be
a) the user manually clicking the `<a>` tag
b) the code calling
`await JsRunTime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFromUrl", 
$"api/Export/GetExportFile?exportId={exportRunner.ExportId}&fileDownloadName={exportRunner.FinalExportFileName}&outputFormatType={exportRunner.OutputFormatType}");`
Then I guess control passes over to the browser and there is no way to determine if the file is fully downloaded into the user's download folder?